# Designing a 4K screen with mobile-friendly buttons. The DPI, DP > PX math is making me mental

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, mobile

Our project (in Unity) is designed for desktop first, at 4k, so 3840 x 2160 and the unit of measure of the canvas is pixels.

I have figured out pt, px, dp, dpi, logical density buckets, etc. and understand that for optimal results, we'll need different resolutions of our UI art for the different buckets, or the highest resolution with mipmaps.

Where I'm stuck is trying to figure out what pixel size on a 4k canvas a button needs to be so that it will be 48dp on mobile.

Android baseline is 160 dpi (mdpi) ... but when people need to build a screen in pixels, what screen size does that correspond to?  I understand that it doesn't, but practically, have to find the best answer.  People have had to solve this problem before, designing a 4k canvas and making sure that the buttons and spacing on it were mobile friendly.

What I tried was taking some device logical resolutions, such as Galaxy S7's 360 x 640, setting that up in photoshop and adding a 48 pixel button, then scaling that up to 4k.  The result was 288.  The result for other device logical resolutions fluctuated varied, of course ... but I think the answer is that on a 4k canvas, for a button to be minimum 48 dp on mobile, it needs to be 288 pixels.

Though density buckets are not the same as screen resolutions, it seems to me that mdpi corresponds fairly well to 360 x 640, and xxhdpi corresponds well to 4k.  I'm thinking this has something to do with the math between the baseline of 160 dpi and the typical ppi of computer monitors being 96.

Anyone much smarter than me able to help shed light on this?

Or anyone have a standard practice for how to build a screen for 4k which is also mobile friendly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no point redrawing all the UI images bases on screen size. You should design your UI to meet all Screen size by optimizing anchors and Pivots. If you are worried about the size of the build, then Unity allows you to compress the textures to the required size.
These guides will be useful to you

1. [Designing UI for all screen sizes](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/08/18/unity-ui-for-different-screen-sizes/)
2. [Reducing Build size in Unity](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/09/15/reduce-your-build-size-in-unity/)

Comment: This answer doesn't relate to the question, but thank you for taking the time to try to help.